# Is it possible to get the axis positions of an arbibrary click event in AG Grid chart?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When using a chart in AG Grid (specifically, in my case, a [standalone AG Chart](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-charts/overview/)), if I attach a listener to the click event of the chart, how can I translate the position of the event to the matching values on the chart's axes (whether numerical or categorical)?  I haven't found any documentation or examples that clarify whether/how I might be able to do this.

I know that I can attach a listener to the seriesNodeClick event, but if there are no data in a particular position of the chart, this won't catch anything (or if I use the option to get the nearest node, the nearest node might not really reflect the location of the click (e.g., it could be in a different category along a categorical axis)).

The last resort may be that I have to get the click event's x/y coordinates, and derive that from the size and and range of a given axis...but that seems clunky and error prone.